# Почему в IDE CodeLobster отображаются не все файлы проекта Laravel

Tags: laravel

Почему в IDE CodeLobster отображаются не все файлы проекта Laravel?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По всей видимости файлы с точкой считаются скрытыми, как и файлы без расширения, почему нету composer и остальных конечно тоже вопрос но порыл бы там же где и настройки отображения файлов в проекте

Comment: нашел в настройках - там перечисляются расширения всех видов файлов. Не подскажете, как одним махом указать все виды расширений и без расширений? Типа: `*.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В закладке <Настройки> потребовалось перечислить все расширения. Все отобразилось. Один файл artisan - командная строка Laravel - без расширения. Не нашёл как отобразить.
Хотя, в общем-то, если есть желание его увидеть, то можно поменять расширение на artisan.php, так как он содержит php-код.
Однако при работе с командной строкой придется указывать тогда полностью его название - artisan.php - что неудобно.